# Acceso denegado al vincular Java-Eclipse con un repositorio privado en GitHub Destok

Tags: java, eclipse, github, github-desktop

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en grupo y en GitHub Destok se ha subido el proyecto como privado.
Al intentar vincular eclipse con GitHub me pide un usuario y contraseña (de github) al introducirlo  me da acceso denegado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar el problema.
Gracias.a

Comment: si el creador del repositorio no eres tu ,dile que te agregue como colaborador

Comment: Si estoy agregada como colaborado pero aún así no me deja hacer los push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede ser que sea que en vez de la contraseña, se deba poner el token de accesso con los permisos para editar (que lo generas vos misma).

Se hace desde:
https://github.com/settings/tokens